# How to static_assert template enum types? (C++11)

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

```
enum PieceType
{
    NoPieceType, Pawn, Knight, Bishop, Rook, Queen, King,
    AllPieces = 0,
    PieceType_N = 8
};

template<PieceType T> Score OutpostEvaluator()
{
    static_assert(T == Bishop || T == Knight); // Doesn't compile.....
}
```

I want to make sure a template function can only be used for certain types of enum values, Bishop and Knight in my case here. std::is_scalar(), std::is_enum() and other type support don't seem to work in my case. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Syntax for `static_assert`, from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert.

```
static_assert ( bool_constexpr , message );
```

You need to provide a message. Something like:

```
static_assert(T == Bishop || T == Knight, "Expected Bishop or Knight");
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in the enum. You just have to add a message to `static_assert`:

```
static_assert(T == Bishop || T == Knight, "message");
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, `static_assert` requires a message, however [n3928](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3928.pdf) proposes a default string literal for `static_assert`, allowing you to omit the message. This has already been implemented in Clang in C++1z mode and as an extension in C++1y/14 mode.

```
static_assert(0);
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c193ed779c0148e3)